# switching between models via keybord in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm writing module for Orchard CMS. I have Projection with several elements? and each element has it's own javascript popup, which appears after clicking "Popup" button.

How can I make switching between popups by keyboard arrows? Every popup get data from it's own model.

Model:

```
<div id="marketpart">
<img src="@(new HtmlString("/Media/Catalog/" + @Model.Path))" alt = "no image" width="200px" height="150px"/><br />
@T("ProductName -") @Model.Name<br />
@T("Art - ") @Model.Art<br />
@T("Packing - ") @Model.Packing<br />
@T("Country - ") @Model.Country<br />
@T("Price - ") @Model.Price<br />
```

```
<div id="@Model.Art" class="popup">
<img src="@(new HtmlString("/Media/Catalog/" + @Model.Path))" alt = "no image" width="200px" height="150px"/><br />
@T("Name - ") @Model.Name<br />
@T("Art - ") @Model.Art<br />
@T("Price - ") @Model.Price<br />
@T("Packing - ") @Model.Packing<br />
@T("Country - ") @Model.Country<br />
<button onclick="closePopup('@Model.Art');" class="price"></button>
```

JS:

```
function showPopup(id) {
var popup = document.getElementById(id);
popup.style.display = 'block';
}

function closePopup(id) {
var popup = document.getElementById(id);
popup.style.display = 'none';
}

document.onkeydown = checkKeycode
function checkKeycode(e) {
var keycode;
if (window.event) keycode = window.event.keyCode;
else if (e) keycode = e.which;
if (keycode == 37) {
    alert("left");
}
if (keycode == 39) {
    alert("right");
}
}
```

So, I need switch between Models where keypressed "left" or "right" (alerts in my code).

Comment: try getting `keyCode` and based on code assign a method to open popup

Comment: yes, I can simply check if keypressed. But how can I move between models for document.getDocumentById() function?

Comment: can you post your existing code? its bit confusing for me

Comment: so you just need to show/hide those two `div`s based on `keyCode` right ?

Comment: no, I have, for example, 2 models on one page, and each model has it's own popup. Based on keycode I need to close first model's popup and open second model's popup.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24034/discussion-between-don-and-max-zhukov)